# Ping wireless interface from wired interface

Tags: networking, wifi, ping

I'm performing some wireless measurements. The setup I'm now using is composed of a WiFi AP and two laptops. One laptop (A) and the AP are connected to a common switch, while the second laptop (B) associate to the AP. Traffic is going from A to B and viceversa.

I would like now to simplify the hardware requirements and replace both laptops with a single embedded PC based on OpenWRT.

My question is then: is it possible to configure a Linux box to send packets out one interface (say the ethernet), over an AP and into another interface (say the wifi) on the same box?

Comment: I was with you *right* up to the last sentence. Then I completely had no clue what you were asking.

Comment: I've edited the question. I hope that now it is more clear.

Comment: I just want to confirm that I understand you right: So your plan is to send out a network packet from wired-interface A of server A, route or bridge through an AP into wifi, and into the wireless-interface of the same Server A? Why would you do that? you can do this communication internally without ever entering the physical network.

Comment: The packet send from the wired interface A should go directly to the AP (trought a simple switch) the Ap should then router the packet back to the box the packet originated from BUT over the wireless interface. I need to do this because I would like to collect some measurements over the wifi link. Now I'm using two dedicated laptop but it would be very useful to me if I could use just one machine doing both TX and RX.